# Unity: collider2D.bounds.Contains not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onmousedown, mouse-position

I've got a *GameController* object with a square 2D collider that covers the whole screen. Inside that GameController there are 7 objects (*Zones*), each one with their own polygon collider.
Here's the setup:

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4jyu.png)

[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmeWo.png)

What I'm trying to do is to check if the clicked position is inside any of those Zone's colliders whenever I click inside the big square collider.

This is the *OnMouseDown()* code of the GameController's script:

```
void OnMouseDown ()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if(this.collider2D.bounds.Contains(mousePos)) Debug.Log ("1st Check");

    //'Zones' is a list with all the Zones GameObjects
    foreach (GameObject zone in Zones)
    {
        if(zone.collider2D.bounds.Contains(mousePos))
        {
            Debug.Log ("2nd Check");
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't I **ALWAYS** get the "1st Check"? Because it's redundant: if the *OnMouseDown()* got triggered because I clicked inside the collider, then the mouse position has to be inside the collider. But I never do, so I think I'm missing something right here about the *Input.mousePosition* or the *ScreenToWorldPoint().*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `.collider2D.bounds.Contains(mousePos)` was getting a Vector3 but should've been receiving a Vector2. 
Changed it to `.collider2D.bounds.Contains(Vector2(mousePos))` and works like charm.